# SQLSyntaxErrorException: Columns of type 'INTEGER' cannot hold values of type 'CHAR'

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, types

i'm not quite sure where i am going wrong here i've tried absolutely everything. Here is my code, I'm trying to update a table where a certain ID is the id entered by the user in the GUI.

myConObj =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SCM_SYSTEM");
            myStatObj = myConObj.createStatement();

```
        Statement add=myConObj.createStatement();
        String x = qtyTxt.getText();
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(x);
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idTxt.getText());



        String sql="update APP.CURRENT_STOCK set ITEM='"+itemTxt.getText()+"'"+
                ", STATUS='STATUS', QTY_REMAINING='QUANTITY_REMANING"+qty+"int"+"'"+
                ", ARRIVAL_DATE='"+adTxt.getText()+"'"+", SIGNED_BY='"+sbTxt.getText()+"'"+
                "where ID="+id;

        add.executeUpdate(sql);
```

The only type INTEGER I have on the table is ID and QUANTITY_REMANING but somehow I keep getting the error mentioned in the title, despite me showing that they are integers.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to print your SQL to console or something before executing it.... Then you would have found that the qty_ part reads something like this:  `QTY_REMAINING='QUANTITY_REMANING1234int'  ` which is not a numeric value..... (Also: putting the word 'STATUS' in your STATUS column could be a mistake....)

Comment: how could i append the number I want to insert into QUANTITY_REMANING to the value that already is in the table?

Comment: You should really look in to PreparedStatements.

Comment: @Mureinik yes I used preparedStatements and got it working thx